# Пишу бота на Python! а именно мягкие(временные) наказания, что бы не засорять ленту в группе

Tags: python

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text and message.text.lower()  and message.chat.id == GROUP_ID)
def set_ro(message):
    bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, until_date=time()+3600)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, strings.get(get_language(message.from_user.language_code)).get("ro_msg"),
                     reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
```

как сделать тоже самое с фото ?

Comment: _"как сделать тоже самое с фото ?"_, — сделать что? Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее, что должен делать код и что не получилось.

Comment: Все разобрался, работает все)) я просто начинающий в Питоне)